# What does `addi a0, zero, 2` mean in pseudocode?

Tags: assembly, riscv, instruction-set

What does `addi a0, zero, 2` mean in pseudocode?
Is it `a0=a0+2`??

I am not sure because we do not have explicit register in this instruction to tell us where goes our result.

Comment: `a0` is the result. `zero` is not `a0`, it's the register hardwired with value zero. So that's basically `a0=0+2`.

Comment: It's their way of doing load immediate 2 into a0.

Comment: Why tag MIPS if this is just about RISC-V?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not so much pseudo code in this risc-v assembly line :

```
addi a0, zero, 2
```

- **addi** : mean **add** **i**mmediate. First argument is the register number for result, second is an argument and last is the immediate value (2 here).

But **a0** and **zero** are ABI name of RISC-V register ([see this pdf page 3](https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/riscv-calling.pdf)).

- **a0**: correspond to register x10. The addition result will be stored here.
- **zero**: correspond to register x0. That is a special register «hardwired» to 0 (always 0 value)

Then the assembly line given will do this :

```
x10 = 0 + 2
```